# Given $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)-f(x)f(y)$ for a decreasing continuous $f$ with $f'(0)=-1$, what are some methods to calculate $\int_0^1f(x)\,\mathrm dx$?

Tags: functions, definite-integrals, functional-equations

My particular question is:

> If $f$ be a decreasing continuous function satisfying
> $$f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)-f(x)f(y) \quad \forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}$$
> and
> $$f'(0)=-1 \text,$$
> then $$\int_0^1f(x) \, \mathrm d x =?$$

Answer to this question is given to be $2-e$.

---

###### My attempt:

$f(0)=0$ by putting value of $x$ and $y$ as $0$ and noticing that $f(x)$ can not be constant.

Then I had some options in question. All of the answers involved $e$ so I tried some trivial values that $f(x)$ might assume but did not succeed in my attempt.

Since $f(0)=0$ and $f$ is a decreasing function hence integral will give a negative value. I managed to do it this far (which appears to be nothing).

---

###### Another attempt:

I tried to differentiate the property of $f$
$$f(x+y)= f(x)+ f(y) -f(x)f(y)$$
$$\implies f'(x+y) = f'(x) + f'(y) -f'(x)f(y) -f(x)f'(y) \text.$$
Putting $x , y = 0$ we get $f(0) = \frac 1 2$. So I think that this method is incorrect, but I don't know where?

Would anyone guide me please? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some hints.

a) Put $g(x)=1-f(x)$. Show that $g(x+y)=g(x)g(y)$ for all $x,y$.

b) Put $y=x$ and show that $g(y)\geq 0$ for all $y$.

c) Suppose that for a $u\in {\mathbb R}$ $g(u)=0$, and show then that $g(x)=0$ for all $x$, and that this imply a contradiction.

d) Now you can put $h(x)=\log g(x)$, and find the form of the (continuous ) fonction $h$.

e) I leave to you the end of the proof.